# The inverse of a Dirichlet product is the Dirichlet product of the inverses of each function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f,g$ be arithmetic functions. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_inverse), $(f*g)^{-1} = f^{-1} * g^{-1}$ if $f(1) \neq 0$ and $g(1) \neq 0$.

However, it is not clear to me why this is true, and the statement does not provide a reference text for a proof. Would anyone be able to provide a link to one and/or prove it?

Comment: Look at the definition of $f \star g$

Comment: $h = (f \ast g)^{-1}$ iff $h \ast f \ast g = \delta$. Since $h=f^{-1} \ast g^{-1}$ satisfies the condition then... Also note the sequences with $f(1) = 1$ are a commutative group under Dirichlet convolution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can look at this question from the group theory perspective. If $a,b$ are elements of an abelian group $G$, then $(a*b)^{-1}$ is $a^{-1} * b^{-1}$. So we just need to prove that all arithmetic functions $f$ such that $f(1) \neq 0$ forms an abelian group.

By definition, the Dirichlet product is commutative and associative. The neutral (i.e. identity) element is

$$I(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n = 1 \\ 0 & n \neq 1 \end{cases}.$$

The inverse of the function $f$ can be found recursively by $f^{-1}(n)$ = $-1/f(1)$ * $\displaystyle\sum_{d|n , d<n}^\mathbb{}f(d)*f^{-1}(n/d)$. Hence we have an abelian group, and our identity is correct because for every group:
$(a*b)^{-1}$ * $(a*b) = e = a^{-1} * b^{-1}$ * $(a*b)$ so we have $(a*b)^{-1}$ = $a^{-1} * b^{-1}$